# composer.json fails to resolve installable set of package

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, composer-php

I can't install `stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle` with my Composer. I'm using Symfony2.1.9 version and a lot of problems are shown. The first one is:

> the requested package  stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle 1.1.* could not be found.

This is my `composer.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.1.*",
        "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.5-dev",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.1.*",
        "twig/extensions": "1.0.*@dev",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.2.*",
        "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.1.*",
        "kriswallsmith/assetic": "1.1.*@dev",
        "pagerfanta/pagerfanta": "dev-master",
        "white-october/pagerfanta-bundle": "dev-master",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "dev-master",
        "saad-tazi/g-chart-bundle": "dev-master",
       "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "1.1.*",
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.1-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

when i set the package requirement to: `"stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "1.1.*@dev"`
the response was: `your requirement could not be resolved to an installable set of package`

what could be the problem please??
should i install DoctrineExtensions first????

error message:

```
Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.10
    - Conclusion: remove symfony/symfony v2.1.9
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.9
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.8
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.7
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.6
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.5
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.4
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.3
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.2
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.1
    - white-october/pagerfanta-bundle dev-master requires symfony/framework-bundle >=2.2,<3.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v2.2.0, v2.2.1], symfony/framework-bundle[v2.2.0, v2.2.1].
    - white-october/pagerfanta-bundle dev-master requires symfony/framework-bundle >=2.2,<3.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v2.2.0, v2.2.1], symfony/framework-bundle[v2.2.0, v2.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.2.0, v2.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.2.1, v2.1.0].
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.0|don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.1|don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.0
    - Installation request for symfony/symfony 2.1.* -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.10, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.1.5, v2.1.6, v2.1.7,v2.1.8, v2.1.9].
    - Installation request for white-october/pagerfanta-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by white-october/pagerfanta-bundle[dev-master].
```

Comment: copy the complete error messages, not only a extract!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The critical part in here is the following:

```
[...]
white-october/pagerfanta-bundle dev-master requires symfony/framework-bundle >=2.2,<3.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v2.2.0, v2.2.1], symfony/framework-bundle[v2.2.0, v2.2.1].
[...]
```

Which can lead to confusion! Let me explain:

Though it says the dependency is satisfiable by updating *symfony/symfony* to 2.2.0 or 2.2.1 ... this update is *NOT NEEDED* !! ( even if updating might be a good idea it is not necessary to resolve the issue and could lead to broken code because of BC [*backward compatibility*] breaks )

**Attention:**

Many bundles have a **legacy branch** ... for example a **2.1.x branch** to support *symfony/symfony* 2.1.

Look for these branches on [packagist](https://packagist.org/) prior to blindly updating your whole project to a new version of the root package!

**Tip**:

Generally if composer fails to fetch a dependency this is often related to the *minimum stability* for one of your required packages. minimum stability of all packages normally defaults to *stable*.

**Solution:**

smarttech used the wrong branch (dev-master) for *white-october/pagerfanta-bundle* to use it with symfony **2.1**. The *correct branch* for 2.1 would have been:

```
"white-october/pagerfanta-bundle": "2.1.*@dev"
```

... where the **@dev** stability flag tells composer to use the *dev* version of doctrine-extensions-bundle for this single package. Please read more about composer's [Stability Flags](https://igor.io/2013/02/07/composer-stability-flags.html).

Take a quick look at the *stability hierarchy*:

```
dev < alpha < beta < rc < stable
```

**Alternative:**

Another way to solve the issue would have been setting composer's [minimum stability](http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability).

Though this is *not recommended* as it applies to all constraints and as a result you will get unstable versions of *all* packages.

```
{

    [...]
    "require" :

        [...]

    "minimum-stability" : "dev",

    [...]

}
```

Comment: minimun-stability: dev is very bad. This will cause all bundles to clone the latest commit. This not helpfull developing own applications.

Comment: Don't do this as it's bad practice.

Comment: so sorry @nifr.please where to write this line.Sorry i am so confused

Comment: @smarttech simply, don't do it.

Comment: Nice @Pazi ... you downvoted my answer and made smarttech unnecessarily update symfony to 2.2 ... So please remove your downvote on my answer which now provides the correct solution and necessary information. thx

Comment: Nothing wrong with using minimum-stability: dev. In fact its absolutely necessary if youre depending on packages that dont have stable versions tagged. Just use it with prefer-stable: true if youre worried about pulling in broken revisions on the packages that do have stable versions tagged

Answer (score 0):

As the 1.1.x branch of the [stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle](https://packagist.org/packages/stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle) is still only available as dev. So you have to declare it as a dev dependency in composer. Simply:

```
"stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "1.1.*@dev"
```

Next time take a look at packagist, which versions are available of a desired bundle.

EDIT: And yes, tested this requirement in a fresh symfony install and it works. So if you have errors, edit the complete error message in your question!

Answer (score 0):

As this is a completly different answer. Your problem is not `stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle`, it's `white-october/pagerfanta-bundle`. Kids, read the error messages!

How i knew this? Simply copied your composer.json, executed update and got a meaning error message:

```
 white-october/pagerfanta-bundle dev-master requires symfony/framework-bundle >=2.2,<3.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v2.2.0, v2.2.1], symfony/framework-bundle[v2.2.0, v2.2.1].
```

which means, **actual versions** of pagerfanta-bundle requires symfony 2.**2**, so you have to upgrade, if you want to use it.

Comment: thnx so much @Pazi ,That goes well now

Comment: @smarttech Pazi pointed you to a WRONG solution. Though it worked for you now ... updating symfony to 2.2 was NOT necessary! In a large project this would have lead to all kinds of BC breaks in your code. My answer now contains all the information. Please accept it as it is the correct one.

Comment: thanks :-) though the hint to " actual versions of pagerfanta-bundle requires symfony 2.2" is not wrong itself ... the right solution would have been just using the right legacy branch.