# Symfony 2.3.7 + Comment Bundle: Compatible?

Tags: symfony, composer-php, symfony-2.3

It seems that the comment bundle is not compatible with the 2.3.7 symfony version.

Can you help me?

config.yml:

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
        "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
        "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "2.3.*",


        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "1.3.*@dev",

        "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "0.12.0",
        "friendsofsymfony/rest": "0.8.0",

        "jms/serializer-bundle": "0.12.0",

        "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "v1.1.2",
        "knplabs/knp-menu": "v1.1.2",

        "liip/imagine-bundle": "v0.17.0",
        "imagine/imagine": "v0.5.0",          

        "rodchyn/cron-manager-bundle": "dev-master",
        "bcc/extra-tools-bundle": "v1.0",

        "symfony/intl": "2.3.*@dev",
        "friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle": "2.0.5"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.3-dev"
        }
    },
     "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
}
```

**Here the error:**

```
 - Installation request for symfony/framework-standard-edition 2.3.x-dev -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-standard-edition[2.3.x-dev].
    - Conclusion: remove symfony/symfony v2.3.7
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.7
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.6
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.5
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.4
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.3
    - Installation request for friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle 2.0.5 -> satisfiable by friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle[v2.0.5].
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.2
    - friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle v2.0.5 requires symfony/symfony >=2.1,<2.3-dev -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.10, v2.1.11, v2.1.12, v2.1.13, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.1.5, v2.1.6, v2.1.7, v2.1.8, v2.1.9, v2.2.0, v2.2.1, v2.2.10, v2.2.11, v2.2.2, v2.2.3, v2.2.4, v2.2.5, v2.2.6, v2.2.7, v2.2.8, v2.2.9].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.1.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.1.10].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.1.11].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.1.12].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.1.13].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.1.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.1.3].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.1.4].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.1.6].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.1.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.1.8].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.1.9].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.2.0].
```

Comment: What version of php are you using. If I recall correctly, some of the symfony components aren't compatible with lower versions of php 5.3. Not sure if this is causing the issue, but it springs to mind. Edit: I think I found a similar problem somebody had. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16672993/composer-json-fails-to-resolve-installable-set-of-package)

Comment: thanks for your answer, I have php version 5.4.10

Answer (score 0):

You are requiring symfony/symfony version 2.3.7. The library friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle version 2.0.5 states that it is not compatible with Symfony 2.3, only with any version 2.1.x or 2.2.x.

Composer tells you that it cannot resolve this conflict.

As a general suggestion, I'd recommend not to state explicit versions of software in your `composer.json` file because it is unflexible when adding new components. Some conflicts might be resolvable by downgrading or upgrading other components as well - which will only happen if you allow these version changes.

For example, the tilde operator is useful for this. By requiring "~2.3" of symfony, you state that you want at least version 2.3.0, but are also happy with any updates until 2.999.999 (i.e. less than 3.0). This works nicely with components that use semantic versioning, which means that the patch version is incremented when bugfixing, the minor version is incremented when adding new features in backwards-compatible ways, and the mayor version is incremented when incompatible changes happen. Usually you'd be happy with any compatible update, so that's why "~2.3" for symfony would be as good as 2.3.*, or even better, because you'd also allow 2.4.0 and beyond - which should be compatible to 2.3.x.

What can you do with the comment-bundle? If you have a look at their Github repo, you see that in the master branch, the composer.json does not impose a "no 2.3 symfony" limit any more.

This version would be available to your software by requiring this:

```
"friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle": "~2.0@dev"
```

Alternatively you could also use the asterisk:

```
"friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle": "2.0.*@dev"
```

The "@dev" allows development versions of 2.0 only for this component, and because the master branch is declared to have the alias "2.0.x-dev", Composer recognizes the master branch as the current development version of 2.0. So "2.0.*@dev" is the most recent version in master, and I expect this version to be compatible with Symfony 2.3.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I have another bug. After `php composer.phar update` friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle v2.0.4 requires jms/serializer 1.0.*@dev -> no matching package found.

Answer (score 0):

Using:

> "friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle": "~2.0@dev"

I have this bug:

```
Problem 1
    - friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle v2.0.4 requires jms/serializer 1.0.*@dev -> no matching package found.
    - don't install friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle 2.0.x-dev|install friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle dev-master
    - Conclusion: don't install friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle dev-master
    - Conclusion: remove symfony/symfony v2.3.7
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.7
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.6
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.5
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.4
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.3
    - Installation request for symfony/framework-standard-edition 2.3.x-dev -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-standard-edition[2.3.x-dev].
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.2
    - Installation request for friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle 0.12.0 -> satisfiable by friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle[0.12.0].
    - symfony/framework-standard-edition 2.3.x-dev requires friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle ~2.0@dev -> satisfiable by friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle[2.0.x-dev, v2.0.0, v2.0.1, v2.0.2, v2.0.3, v2.0.4, v2.0.5].
    - friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle v2.0.0 requires symfony/symfony 2.1.* -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.10, v2.1.11, v2.1.12, v2.1.13, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.1.5, v2.1.6, v2.1.7, v2.1.8, v2.1.9].
    - friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle v2.0.1 requires symfony/symfony 2.1.* -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.10, v2.1.11, v2.1.12, v2.1.13, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.1.5, v2.1.6, v2.1.7, v2.1.8, v2.1.9].
    - friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle v2.0.2 requires symfony/symfony 2.1.*@stable -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.10, v2.1.11, v2.1.12, v2.1.13, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.1.5, v2.1.6, v2.1.7, v2.1.8, v2.1.9].
    - friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle v2.0.3 requires symfony/symfony 2.1.*@stable -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.10, v2.1.11, v2.1.12, v2.1.13, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.1.5, v2.1.6, v2.1.7, v2.1.8, v2.1.9].
    - friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle v2.0.5 requires symfony/symfony >=2.1,<2.3-dev -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.10, v2.1.11, v2.1.12, v2.1.13, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.1.5, v2.1.6, v2.1.7, v2.1.8, v2.1.9, v2.2.0, v2.2.1, v2.2.10, v2.2.11, v2.2.2, v2.2.3, v2.2.4, v2.2.5, v2.2.6, v2.2.7, v2.2.8, v2.2.9].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.1.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.1.10].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.1.11].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.1.12].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.1.13].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.1.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.1.3].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.1.4].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.1.6].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.1.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.1.8].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.1.9].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.2.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.2.10].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.2.11].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.2.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.2.3].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.2.4].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.2.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.2.6].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.2.8].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.2.9].
    - symfony/framework-standard-edition 2.3.x-dev requires symfony/symfony 2.3.* -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v2.3.7, v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.2, v2.3.3, v2.3.4, v2.3.5, v2.3.6].
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.1
```